# Looking for a third-party iOS library that provides drag and drop functionality

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a third-party iOS library that provides following features:

- Grid or List view display
- Move item/cell, using drag and drop, from one view to another
- If similar item/cell already exists in the target view, ignore the move operation
- Allow the user to delete item/cell by making the view "Editable"
- Auto-adjust the grid or list when a item/cell is added or removed

So far I've evaluated the following libraries, but none of these do all the above:

- [iOS DragAndDrop by brynbellomy](https://github.com/brynbellomy/iOS-DragAndDrop)
- [RGDragAndDrop by frenetisch-applaudierend](https://github.com/frenetisch-applaudierend/RGDragAndDrop)
- [GMGridView by gmoledina](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView)
- [HGKDragAndDropRecycleBin by Hegaka](https://github.com/Hegaka/HGKDragAndDropRecycleBin)
- [HMLauncherView by heikomaass](https://github.com/heikomaass/HMLauncherView)
- [JDDroppableView by jaydee3](https://github.com/jaydee3/JDDroppableView)
- [iPad-UITableView-DnD-Demo by josh2112](https://github.com/josh2112/iPad-UITableView-DnD-Demo)
- [TKDragView by mapedd](https://github.com/mapedd/TKDragView)

HMLauncherView is pretty good, but it doesn't provide me the following features:

- Auto-adjust the grid or list when a item/cell is added or removed
- If similar item/cell already exists in the target view, ignore the move operation

Any other suggestions?

Comment: +1 for listing potentially useful libraries.

Comment: I am looking for one that can allow me to move views by drag and drop and dock them in specified locations. Thanks for the list. I'll take a look and see which one gives me what I'm looking for.

Comment: The link to frenetisch-applaudierend's RGDragAndDrop is broken.